# Table Cell Not Growing to its Contents Size

Tags: css

I have a very simple table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<!-- NOTE: min-width is just to make the td's outline more visible -->
            <td style="border: 1px dotted blue; min-width:130px;">
                <span style="padding: 50px; background:red">x</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, I'm confused by what it produces.  I would have expected the `<td>` to grow to the size of its contents, giving me a blue dotted line surrounding a big block of red.

That doesn't happen though.  Instead, the row's height remains fixed (as you can see by looking at the blue line), and the inner `<span>` spills out past the `<td>`, without changing it.

Clearly I'm misunderstanding how table cells grow, as I thought they would always expand to fit their contents (unless I use, say, `overflow: hidden`).  Can anyone please explain:

1. why my `<td>` isn't growing to encompass its `<span>`?
2. what CSS I could use to make it encompass its span?

P.S. I did try searching for an answer to this, but all I could find was people trying *not* to have their `<td>` grow (implying that, by default, they do grow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the inline level element `<span>`+ `padding`. If you set it to `span { display: block; }`, it will then all work as expected.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ua2aj9x/)

```css
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
<!-- NOTE: min-width is just to make the td's outline more visible -->
            <td style="border: 1px dotted blue; min-width:130px;">
                <span style="padding: 50px; background:red">x</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh!  I was thinking completely in terms of block elements, and didn't consider the "strangeness" of inline rendering.  Thank you!

Comment: Yep that happens, there is a good post here, it might explain more - https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/